# Amazon Alexa on Raspberry Pi bash: mvn: command not found

Tags: alexa-voice-service

I am following the instructions on Amazon's Github (https://github.com/alexa/alexa-avs-sample-app/wiki/Raspberry-Pi) to set up Alexa on the Raspberry Pi. I was able to complete the steps until Step 7, where I was running the sample app on AVS. When I copy and pasted:

cd ~/Desktop/alexa-avs-sample-app/samples
cd javaclient && mvn exec:exec

as instructed into a separate terminal, i received the error

bash: mvn: command not found

I have been following the instructions to the T and am not sure exactly why I would be receiving this error (or any error). Any thoughts?

Comment: try `. automated_install.sh` after `sudo su`, since there are some instructions in `automated_install.sh` which require admin privileges, It worked for me...

Answer (score 0):

1. Open */etc/apt/sources.list* on your raspberry pi terminal `sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list`
2. Check if it has following lines. Modify accordingly to have following lines:

   ```
   deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi
   deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main
   deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main
   ```
3. Run `sudo apt-get update`
4. Run the `sudo bash Desktop/alexa-avs-sample-app/automated_install.sh` again if needed.